# Is it possible to use Google Cloud Run to Docker Pull?

Tags: google-cloud-run

Is it possible to use Google Cloud Run to perform a Docker Pull and host an image such as a document or graph database?  Can we attach a volume where the data is persisted?

Answer (score 1):

**If  you're trying to ask "Can I deploy any image to Cloud Run":** Yes, however Cloud Run supports only HTTP protocol and doesn't allow much room for background processing that most databases do. So document/graph databases probably won't work. Also Cloud Run currently doesn't support persistent storage volumes, so you'd have hard time persisting the data written by the database.

---

**If you're trying to ask "Can I pull a docker image inside a Cloud Run container"** (not sure why  you'd  do that): Cloud Run can do most  things. At the end of the day, `docker pull` is just  retrieving  bunch of tar files and extracting them. You  can read the [reference docs](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#pulling-an-image). Extracting the image  may  require special processing since you won't have access to COW (copy on write) filesystem drivers like overlayfs, but you  can implement  this yourself. However,  most docker images will be  100s of MBs, and any time you write files to local disk on Cloud Run, it counts towards your memory, so if you pull and extract a 200 MB image, you can easily crash  your Cloud Run container if it has 512 MiB memory.

Comment: Let me see if I can reword my pre-sales question.  Can Google Cloud Run host a vendor's official image Pulled from Docker Hub instead of Google's Registry?  Do I understand your answer correct... none of the containers hosted in Google Cloud Run can be configured with the -v option during Run to connect with a persistent volume where a database repository or log file (that we need to exist after a container failure) can be located?

Comment: You can deploy pre-build images, but will need to copy them to Google Container Registry first. (Simple docker pull/docker push can do this)

Comment: Logs are real time moved to Stackdriver, from there you can export them various ways: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/logging, https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/